# Move div to be directly after another div with plain / native js?

Tags: javascript

Many may ask why in the desire to see if it’s really needed. While  undesirable it is for this particular use case which won’t detail since not relevant to the answer. It’s easily accomplished with a line of JQuery but alas needs to be plain js and ideally as short and straightforward as possible. See similar requests on SO but many for moving inside a div or with slightly more complex requirements.

Created a basic example that works as desired:

```js
var contentDiv = document.querySelector('.c');
var anchorDiv = document.querySelector('.b');
contentDiv.after(anchorDiv);
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="a">
    A
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    B
  </div>
  <div class="c">
    C
  </div>
</div>
```

When doing it on the real code however get the error:

> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'contentDiv.after')

While having the script at the top of the page can cause that, have it at the bottom, so is there anything else that might be causing that?

The actual code using is the following incase the specific class names are problematic?:

```
<script>
  var contentDiv = document.querySelector('.product-description');
  var anchorDiv = document.querySelector('.product-details__container');
  contentDiv.after(anchorDiv);
</script>
```

Also thought maybe I need a document ready on that. So did:

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var contentDiv = document.querySelector('.product-description');
  var anchorDiv = document.querySelector('.product-details__container');
  contentDiv.after(anchorDiv);
}, false);
</script>
```

But same error. Any ideas?

Comment: @mplungjan [after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/after)

Comment: Perhaps show an example of the "real" html?

Comment: My guess is `document.querySelector('.product-description')` returns null (also note that your question title has nothing to do with the actual problem). In case your page is populated by ajax for instance, you need to run the code after the population obviously.

Comment: @ChrisG Sorry not sure what you mean. The title is moving a div to an new location that is after another div using plain javascript (aka not jquery). That's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @mplungjan It's a lot of code, so first hoping to see if there is a general simple answer such as  needing to do document ready equivalent in certain way etc, but if people feel the above should work and it's presumably some other code on the page causing that error, then yes the next steps would be trying to add more of the code here.

Comment: Yeah, but you know how to do this and you're successfully doing it right in your question. Your actual problem is the fact that `document.querySelector('.product-description')` doesn't find the element and returns `null` instead. Which is completely unrelated to moving divs around.

Comment: A [mcve] is all we need

Comment: @mplungjan I don't see the error listed on that page and resolution on resolving the error on that page. As mentioned when doing a basic example it works but not when using the real class names.

Comment: The link is to a page describing what we like to see here at SO. The code you post works. So post the code that doesn't work. As part of that you might even find the error yourself

Comment: @mplungjan So to clarify, you are saying the above code should work with those class names (no syntax error or anything), but that the error is appearing because of some other code on the page that could cause that? If so, then yes, then next step would be to slowly try to figure out what part of the large dynamic page might be causing it.

Comment: @cchiera Exactly!

Comment: @mplungjan Sorry I meant to right that to "Andy". He had your name in his comment with a link to after. So thought you right that comment but see now he was actually just mentioning you for some reason.

Comment: A simple `console.log("contentDiv:", contentDiv);` will confirm that `contentDiv` is null, which is what causes the error. Which means there's no element matching the selector at the time the code runs.

Comment: The link was because I mistakenly posted that .after was a jQuery construct, not having realised that `.after` is available in DOM too

Comment: @ChrisG The system that lets me add the JS says it gets added to bottom of the page (and it does), but oddly it also adds it to the top of the page it has, "script type = "application/javascript"
data - cookieconsent = "ignore" >
 window.__BOOTSTRAP_STATE__ = {
  "siteData": { with the js code there as well. Assume thus its being run at the top causing the issue and the document doesn't try to run it again when it sees it at the bottom.

Comment: If you're using a CMS that's breaking the code, that's a different problem altogether. Not sure how we're supposed to help you here.

Comment: @ChrisG It's showing the code normally at the bottom, but it's also repeating it in a special way at the top oddly. So instead will need to reform the question to hopefully find some additional code I can wrap it in, so it will only get read the second time, or won't try to read until presumably the whole page is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you AJAX some of the page, you many not HAVE that element with that class at the time the code runs

Try this to see if it eventually works, then you know why

```js
const swap = () => {
  const contentDiv = document.querySelector('.product-description');
  const anchorDiv = document.querySelector('.product-details__container');
  if (contentDiv && anchorDiv) contentDiv.after(anchorDiv);
  else {
    console.log({contentDiv},{anchorDiv})
    setTimeout(swap,1000)
  }
};
window.addEventListener('load', swap);
```

Comment: You are a god among men. That worked! This page I imagine has ajax and a cluster f of code (not developed by me). I'll work on adjusting the timeout (even though appears to load normally instantly), etc. Thank you! Will test more and then accept this.

Comment: Seems you should find out where the ajax occurs and add your swap in the "done" part